# Extracting values from Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, response, speech-recognition

I'm quite new to programming and I'm working on a vocal assistant using Python. I found this code on Github but he doesn't works as he should. Here is the code :

```
def Play(speech):
if speech.endswith("on YouTube"):
    searchTerm = speech.split()
    response = get("https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=" + quote(" ".join(searchTerm[:-2])))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
    videos = soup.findAll(attrs={"class":"yt-uix-tile-link"})[1:4]
    #Was [:3], changed to [1:4] to try to stop ads
    #Try to remove google ads if possible (May have fixed, but test this)
    names = list()
    links = list()
    for i in range(len(videos)):
        names.insert(i, videos[i]["title"])
        links.insert(i, "https://www.youtube.com" + videos[i]["href"])
    print("I found 3 videos. " + ". ".join(names), links)
```

The URL passed as parameter in the get() method works correctly, the soup variable too, but there is nothing in "videos" so nothing is printed at the end and I don't know how to resolve this.

Some ideas please :) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you `cant` get the contents of a dynamic website like `youtube` using requests. sorry to be so direct, but this is the truth.

you need first to `get` to the url, then render the response using something like `chromium` in the background, then pass the results to beautiful soup.

the rendering will take 1-2 seconds. this is how its done.

there is a snippet for extracting the dynamic website contents which then are passed to `BeautifulSoup`

```py
# pip install playwright
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright
# after installing you will get prompted
# to install `chromium`, the `thing` i was talking about
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_dynamic_soup(url: str) -> BeautifulSoup:
    with sync_playwright() as p:
        # Launch the browser
        browser = p.chromium.launch()

        # Open a new browser page
        page = browser.new_page()

        # Open our test file in the opened page
        page.goto(url)

        # Process extracted content with BeautifulSoup
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content(), "html.parser")

        browser.close()

        return soup

# quote is defined in your code
_url = "https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=" + quote(" ".join(searchTerm[:-2]))
soup = get_dynamic_soup(_url)
# now you can do whatever you want with the soup
```

then you can do your stuff:

```py
videos = soup.findAll(attrs={"class":"yt-uix-tile-link"})[1:4]
```

#### to install playwright

```sh
python -m pip install playwright # this installs the python package
python -m playwright install # this install the chromium executable
```

docs for [installation](https://playwright.bootcss.com/python/docs/installation)

*EDIT*
i found a bug in your code
this line

```
videos = soup.findAll(attrs={"class":"yt-uix-tile-link"})[1:4]
```

is wrong because you need to specify the HTML element you want to search for

a good example is:

```
videos = soup.findAll("div", attrs={
    "class": "yt-uix-tile-link"
})[1:4]
# or 
videos = soup.findAll("span", attrs={
    "class": "yt-uix-tile-link"
})[1:4]
# or whatever element it is
```

Comment: Thank you, I just have an error : playwright._impl._api_types.Error: Executable doesn't exist at C:\Users\yayaa\AppData\Local\ms-playwright\chromium-939194\chrome-win\chrome.exe . I don't know because Chromium is installed

Comment: forgot to mention. you need to run this `python -m playwright install` to install chromium. this will install the chromium executable.

Comment: so i guess its working now.

Comment: No error now, but videos is always empty, I think the problem is here : soup.findAll(attrs={"class":"yt-uix-tile-link"})[1:4] . Maybe the class name is wrong or something else ?

Comment: yeah. you need to specify which HTML element (div / span / table / .. ) are you selecting

Comment: yess but which one test ? everything ? :)

Comment: i found this element `ytd-video-renderer` which appears many times inside the `<div id="contents" class="style-scope ytd-item-section-renderer">`

Comment: i dont really know man, i cant code for you. you need to know what you are looking for